# Why is the width of the Drop Down menu isn't similar to my collapse navigation bar's link

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a responsive navbar using BS4 but the problem I am facing is that when the nav is in full width the dropdown menu is alright. However, in collapse mode, the drop-down menu is pushed to the side. And I want the width to be the as the link and also to be positioned correctly

What I've tried:

```css
.navbar{
 background-color:rgb(0,114,187);
 font-family:"Roboto Condensed", "Microsoft YaHei", "Microsoft JhengHei",sans-serif;
}

#navbar10 .navbar-nav .nav-link{
 color:white;
 font-family:"Roboto Condensed", "Microsoft YaHei", "Microsoft JhengHei", sans-serif;
 font-size:14px;

}

.nav-link:hover{
 color:white;
 background-color:rgb(0,34,59);
}

.about.dropdown-menu {
  left: 50% !important;
  transform: translateX(-50%) !important;
  top: 100% !important;
}

.dropdown-menu{
 width:250px;
}

a.dropdown-item{
 text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
    <div class="container">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar10">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar10">
            <ul class="navbar-nav nav-fill w-100">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="Index.html">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown" class = "about">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">About Us</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Introduction</a>
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Mission</a>
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Vision</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Result
[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2t1e.png)

Comment: keywords that are missing: same as the link

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56233957/edit) to post the code as text instead of an image? This is harder to read and the content is not searchable, so it has less value to the Stack Overflow community. A better formed question will get you better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `margin:0 auto` for `drop-down menu`

```
.dropdown-menu{
    width:250px;
    margin:0 auto !important;
}
```

```css
.navbar{
    background-color:rgb(0,114,187);
    font-family:"Roboto Condensed", "Microsoft YaHei", "Microsoft JhengHei",sans-serif;
}

#navbar10 .navbar-nav .nav-link{
    color:white;
    font-family:"Roboto Condensed", "Microsoft YaHei", "Microsoft JhengHei", sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;

}

.nav-link:hover{
    color:white;
    background-color:rgb(0,34,59);
}

.about.dropdown-menu {
  left: 50% !important;
  transform: translateX(-50%) !important;
  top: 100% !important;
}

.dropdown-menu{
    width:250px;
    margin:0 auto !important;
}

a.dropdown-item{
    text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
        <div class="container">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar10">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar10">
                <ul class="navbar-nav nav-fill w-100">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="Index.html">Home</a>
                    </li>
                     <li class="nav-item dropdown" class = "about">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">About Us</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Introduction</a>
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Mission</a>
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Vision</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

[check this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Udhaytitus/1xdwLekp/1/)